# Trying to run Ionic 2 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm, ionic2

I am trying to set up my first project for Ionic 2 in Visual Studio 2015.  I keep getting this error when I run the project....

"You're almost ready! If you're seeing this page, then you still need to install the NPM Task Runner extension for Visual Studio and run this app again. "

I have installed the NPM Task Runner and can see that it is installed when I look at Tools -> Extensions and Updates.  I have Node.js and NPM installed and updated.  I have updated Visual Studio to look at the installed Node.js folder instead of it's internal library.  I have restarted, I still get this error.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you open up your cmd unrelated to VS and type in npm -v does it find NPM?

Comment: I think you are missing the point, if you are setting up your project locally, then create the project using cmd "ionic start projectname --v2"..,then open the project in VS (just editor).,I hope you are not trying to run it in VS

Comment: I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, installed NPM Task Runner, then the Ionic 2 Templates and everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, installed NPM Task Runner, then the Ionic 2 Templates and everything works perfect.